# AndroidTV raw particular focusing

Tags: android, xml, android-tv

**I have the next UI:**

[image: Scheme]

When user uses D-pad in recyclerview I want to focus "Part 1" by default and if button down pressed. But if user pressed button right when current focus is in "Part 1" focus must be changed to "Part 2" (and to "Part 1" if left arrow button pressed and current focus is in Part 2).

My current logic is default - when clicking button down all item / adapter raw is focused.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/item_touch_selector"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_channels"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_channels"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LLPart1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorF5F5F5"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
                    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@color/colorF5F5F5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:paddingStart="13dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_content_name"
                    tools:text="ICTV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/font_gilroy_medium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVC"
                    android:text="@string/item_categories"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/font_gilroy_regular"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LLPart2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_icon_fav"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_likenormal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/VSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black20Per"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**What should I change to achieve expected result?**

I've tried some combinations of

```
android:focusableInTouchMode=""
android:focusable=""
```

but with no result.

**UPD from 14.01.2021:**

So I've tried the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/item_touch_selector"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_channels"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_channels"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LLPart1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/LLPart2"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/LLPart1"
            >
            
            <requestFocus />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorF5F5F5"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
                    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@color/colorF5F5F5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:paddingStart="13dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_content_name"
                    tools:text="ICTV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/font_gilroy_medium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVC"
                    android:text="@string/item_categories"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/font_gilroy_regular"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LLPart2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/LLPart1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_icon_fav"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_likenormal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/VSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black20Per"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**But still all LinearLayout "LL"(all raw) is selected (instead of only "LLPart1"). Right and left arrows do nothing.**

Answer (score 0):

Use **requestFocus** for default focused view and use **nextFocusUp/Down/Left/Right** for each view

Comment: Thanks for idea, I've tried this and update my question. Unfortunately, still not working.